# What happens to tip vortices in a sideslip?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing-tip-vortex, sideslip

Say you're in a right sideslip. What happens to tip vortices? I'm fairly sure that it would just reduce the strength of the vortex (for the left wing), because there is a force trying to keep the high pressure under the wing, if that makes sense. That force is the freestream because the wing is at an angle.

The right wing vortex would probably grow in strength, because that same force is helping the air escape from under the wing. (if I had to guess)

Comment: All of this with just a straight rectangular wing. No winglets or anything.

Comment: Think about what happens if the wing has dihedral, anhedral...

Comment: I have seen some info about this, about the existence of wingtip vortices on a flat (no-dihedral/anhedral) wing causing either an anhedral-like or dihedral-like effect (roll torque) in a sideslip.  Will try and locate and come back with an actual answer.  It is a good question.

Comment: @quietflyer oh okay great! Thanks

Comment: Desktop Aeronautics has a paper out that can be found on the internet.  There is a rolling motion cause by differences in wingtip airflow patterns when the wing is "oblique".  Apparently (good for slips), the lead tip tends to roll *down*, somewhat canceling dihedral effect.

Comment: Wake (not tip) vortices will stay as strong as they were in straight flight and be of equal strength on both sides. Since neither the aircraft nor the wake are rolling but stay level, lift must be balanced. Lift differences from dihedral effects will be canceled by aileron deflection as appropriate to maintain level flight. The wake vortices will move away from the airplane at the sideslip angle since they stay with the local air.

Comment: @PeterKampf -- I guess one way to look at the question is how does the lateral shift in  the tip vortices affect the aileron inputs required to balance the aircraft in roll.  Once those aileron inputs are being made then yes I suppose both vortices will be equal in strength or nearly so.  Your comment more nearly addresses the *actual question* which didn't really ask specifically about how the vortices affect the net roll torque created by slip (in the absence of aileron correction to maintain the bank angle)-- guess I just jumped right to the roll torque issue because I find it interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The following quote is from "Oblique Flying Wings: An Introduction and White Paper" from Desktop Aeronautics, Inc., available at https://www.desktop.aero/library/ofwwhitepaper.pdf.

> 2.2.2 Effect of Oblique Sweep on Spanwise Lift Distribution
>
> A well-known effect of wing sweep is the variation of induced downwash
> along the span from the trailing wake that produces an additional lift
> distribution characterized by increased loading on the aft wing and
> reduced additional lift on the forward wing. For a wing with no twist
> or bend, this results in a significant rolling moment, tending to roll
> the forward wing downward. There is also a yawing moment from the
> asymmetrical distribution of induced drag that tends to unsweep the
> wing.

Keep in mind that by "wing sweep" the authors are talking about obliquely sweeping both wings *together* as a unit, like in the photo in [this other answer to the present question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/104375/34686).  We have essentially the same effect when we sideslip.  The direction of the roll torque generated is toward the "forward" wing, which in a sideslip is the "upwind wing".  In a steady-state non-turning sideslip this would also be the "lowered" wing.  This is an anhedral-like effect.

In the paper they recommend adding a small amount of dihedral to the outboard portions of an oblique-wing aircraft to counteract this, with the amount of dihedral being dependent on the lift coefficient that the aircraft is intended to fly at.

I'd suggest that this effect due to "the variation of induced downwash along the span" falls within the scope of the question's focus on "tip vortices".

The anhedral-like (upwind) roll torque generated by an unswept, zero-dihedral wing in a sideslip was also the subject of a post on an aerodynamics subforum of the"RCGroups" model-airplane on-line forum by a prolific, knowledgeable contributor with the username "ShoeDLG".  Some excerpts from [his post](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=25406195&postcount=34):

> I used a Vortex Lattice Method to explore the impact of various
> Radian Pro wing design features on apparent dihedral effect.
>
> The cases I looked at (all without any twist):
>
> 1. Untapered / Unswept / Zero Dihedral Wing (flat AR 10 rectangular wing)..."

and then

> The results are shown in the first attachment. A couple of
> observations:
>
> 1. A flat rectangular AR 10 wing has negative apparent dihedral effect at positive AOA and positive apparent dihedral effect at negative
>    AOA..."

and then

> The dihedral effect associated with an untapered, unswept, zero
> dihedral wing is interesting. The span loading for an AR 10
> rectangular wing at 5 degrees AOA and 20 degrees sideslip (to
> exaggerate the asymmetry) is shown in the second attachment."

These conclusions are consistent with the "Oblique Flying Wings" white paper-- during a sideslip, on an aircraft with flat (no dihedral or anhedral) wings with no sweep, the lift distribution is changed in a way that creates an "upwind" roll torque-- i.e. an anhedral-like effect.

Here are the two attachments:

[image]

[image]

However, a web page called [www.flightlab.net](http://www.flightlab.net) by Bill Crawford came to the opposite conclusion, stating that during a sideslip, tip vortices shifted in a way that *increased* the angle-of-attack of the *upwind* wing and *decreased* the angle-of-attack of the *downwind* wing, contributing a *dihedral-like* roll torque component, toward the *downwind* wing.  A full page of text devoted to the topic, along with an illustration, may be seen on page 14 of his generally excellent PDF "Flightlab Ground School: 4. Lateral/Directional Stability", now viewable [only on this link on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210423072734/http://www.flightlab.net/Flightlab.net/Download_Course_Notes_files/4_LateralDirectional%232BA14D.pdf).  This content is well worth reading through.

Crawford goes on to reach the following conclusion: (footnotes added)

> "Since downwash strength is a function of CL, pulling or pushing on
> the stick will affect roll moment due to sideslip in a manner similar
> to the swept-wing example already described.<sup>1</sup> (Our trainers’
> rectangular planforms tend to promote strong tip vortices. Other
> straight-wing planforms with different lift distributions might not be
> as effective.)"

followed by:

> From all the above, an under-appreciated yet nevertheless great truth
> of airmanship emerges: For a swept or a straight wing, pulling the
> stick back tends to increase rolling moments caused by sideslip (and
> by yaw rate), pushing decreases them.

(In the specific case of an unswept wing, Crawford is obviously assuming that there is *some* aspect of the aircraft's overall geometry, such as a high wing position, or actual dihedral, or perhaps just the tip vortices themselves, that results in an overall dihedral-like roll torque during a sideslip.  The comment above wouldn't make sense for, say, a low-wing airplane with no sweep and a great deal of *actual anhedral*, because then the effect that he is claiming for the wingtip vortices, which are most pronounced at high Cl, would be acting in the wrong direction.)

So Crawford is reaching the opposite conclusion on the effect of tip vortices on the balance of roll torque during a sideslip than the other sources cited above-- he is claiming that they contribute a dihedral-like roll torque component, toward the downwind wing.  I can't account for this discrepancy at present.  Is it possible that Crawford's conclusions are valid for wings of a certain geometry, such as the low-aspect ratio wings with broad wingtips found on many trainers?  Or is he simply mistaken in the idea that tip vortices, and the associated larger upwash / downwash flow field around the wings, tend to contribute a dihedral-like, downwind roll torque component during a sideslip? Should his observation of increased rolling moments due to sideslip at high lift coefficients versus at low lift coefficients, even in unswept wings, be explained by other means entirely?

Footnotes:

1. I.e. adding to the dihedral-like roll torque that would be created by sweep

Comment: Obviously I've jumped right to the topic of how do the tip vortices and other associated aspects of the flow field tend to generate a roll torque during a sideslip.  That wasn't actually the focus of the question but hope it is somewhat helpful and interesting.

Comment: Excellent resources.  Crawford states that rolling away from the side slip (lead wing) **theoretically** would happen even if dihedral was not present.  Oblique wing testing data may have shown other wise.  Super +1 up to that point.  Data presented by "ShoeDLG" supports (extensive) oblique wing studies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One question : what is meant by “tip vortices shifted in a way that increased the angle-of-attack of the upwind wing and decreased the angle-of-attack of the downwind wing”? I guess I’m asking why Crawford thinks the upwind wing has an increase in AoA, and the downwind has a decrease.

Comment: That is really interesting! Your clarity has provided valued insight in answering this question.  Thank you!

Comment: @Wyatt -- if you follow the "wayback machine" link and look at his actual figure on page 14 of the PDF it might help; I was trying to puzzle it through as typing the answer and couldn't really clearly see why he was coming to that conclusion.

Comment: (ctd) Looking at it again now I do notice that he has drawn the curved arrows representing the tip vortices *larger* for the left (downwind) wing than for the right (upwind) wing so maybe he is suggesting that by being shifted more toward the wing, the upwind tip vortex gets *diminished* in intensity, i.e. the wing itself interferes with the vortex much as a winglet or endplate would? If that's what he was thinking I wish he would have spelled it out explicitly in the text as that point would bear directly on your *actual question* more than the resulting roll trim effct that I was focusng on.

Comment: (ctd) Anyway *if* that actually happened, then the resulting change in downwash velocities over the wing would *seem* to be expected to *contribute* to a dihedral-like downwind roll torque, like he is saying, but the results given in the White Paper on oblique wings and the results of "ShoeDLG's" vortex lattice analysis suggest that the overall complete effect of the shift in the overall flow field due to sideslip actually causes the opposite effect.

Comment: (ctd) Both *could* be true at once: it *could* be true that the energy contained in the immediate area of the tip vortex gets decreased in the upwind wing, yet the net overall effect of the overall shift in the flow field ends up contributing a net anhedral-like upwind roll torque nonetheless.

Comment: (ctd) I may end up adding some of the above conjecture as a footnote to the answer later.   Possibly along with a screenshot of the figure on page 14 of the Wayback Machine link.  Possibly along with a little note at the start pointing out that this answer is focussing on one specific aspect of how sideslip affects the tip vortices and other associated aspects of the flow field, namely their effect on roll trim.

Comment: @Wyatt -- btw I have noticed that another RC glider, the basic "Radian" which lacks ailerons and has *much* more dihedral than the "Radian Pro", in sustained *inverted* flight is much more roll-responsive to rudder inputs with the nose more earthward (wing at small negative lift coefficient) than with the nose more skyward (wing at a large negative lift coefficient).  The opposite of what you'd expect from a wing with no dihedral or anhedral, but lots of sweep.  In inverted flight, from an external viewpoint, the wing has anhedral not dihedral,

Comment: (ctd) and depends on that anhedral for the rudder-roll coupling to work, so a dihedral-like roll torque contribution from the tip vortex displacement like Crawford was claiming *could* be one possible explanation.  I can think of some other things too though, like high-speed flight causing some of the anhedral to be removed as the  rather flexible wing "unbows" due to the way that the washout moves the (negative) lift distribution further outboard when the (negative) a-o-a is lower compared to when the (negative) a-o-a is higher.

Comment: ctd)  For example at very slight neg a-o-a (very high speed inverted flight), one might expect *only* the (washed-out) tips to be making any (negative) lift at all, while the inboard sections are making zero lift or very slight positive lift, which would tend to "unbow" the wing.  Would want to use an onboard camera to rule out that this is happening, before claiming that the observed results actually support the effect Crawford is claiming.  Or replicate tests with a much less flexible wing -- and possibly with zero washout.

Comment: @PeterKampf -- comment above beginning "Looking at it again now I do notice that he has drawn the curved arrows representing the tip vortices larger for the left (downwind) wing than for the right (upwind) wing" bears on your comment (under question) suggesting that the vortices will stay the same in intensity.

Comment: @quietflyer thanks for the detailed response! If I had to guess, I’d say that Crawford might be right when the wing planform is a certain way, like said in your answer. Particularly when it’s a low aspect ratio wing.

Answer (score 1):

In consideration of level flight, if we think about dihedral, the wing yawed into the wind would develop increased lift relative to the other wing, and we would expect the lift-induced vortex on the wing yawed into the wind to be stronger than on the other wing.  This would occur in gliding flight and can be easily demonstrated in general, even though this is not exactly level flight.  However, in powered flight with a single-engine propeller on a mid-wing aircraft, the propeller slipstream may increase lift on the down-wind wing more than dihedral would increase lift on the upwind wing in a side slip.  The consequence will likely cause a roll in the direction of the upwind wing. Now the question remains, in this circumstance which vortex would be increased?  If we consider the total-potential circulation to be more strongly shifted toward the down-wind wing as a consequence of the propeller slip stream, then we would expect that the down-wind wing would have the stronger tip vortex.  Nevertheless, this result is counterintuitive and seemingly unexpected.

There are relatively few in-depth resources discussing in detail this aspect of flight.  quiet flyer will likely have a more informed perspective.

---

Or do you mean something *mostly like this?*[image] Robert T. Jones, at NASA, rather extensively investigated this aspect of flight.  Various summaries and perspectives of his work in this area are readily available on the internet, particularly via NASA.  This particular configuration of the wing is termed *oblique.* In this case, for level flight, there is no apparent asymmetry in the relative distribution of lift.

Answer (score 0):

A crucial difference between slip and oblique data is that slip data (for roll behavior) must include(net) dihedral effect from  relative wind on wing, fuselage and vertical stabilizer, whereas oblique tests only change the orientation of the wing.

This allows us to isolate the effects of oblique sweep on roll behavior and analyze them more accurately.

It is possible the "upwind" or "reverse swept" wing's airstream flow *into* the fuselage degrades the low pressure area over the wing, but the "sweep" of the downwind wing's airstream flow helps preserve it, resulting in a roll (from lift imbalance) *into* the upwind wing.

This is supported by winglet studies and [bird-like](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etrich_Taube) aircraft design.

Amazingly, the data supports 2 major features which could help make the design viable:

1. Rolling tendency can be controlled with +/- dihedral in design
2. Since rolling effect is increased by increase in AoA, it would
   make sense to straighten the wing out at lower speeds (when AoA
   must be greater) to mitigate the effect.

Other concerns are with fluttering tendencies of reverse swept wing tips, which, if overcome, could lead a path to a practical, economical way to increase to flight envelope of an aircraft into the transonic, and even supersonic regimes.

Comment: I don't see the term "tip vortices" or singular "vortex" in your answer.  So what happens to them?

Comment: @MichaelHall the relative wind may push the vortex further into the upwind wingtip and further away from the downwind wingtip.  This is supported by the windflow across the upwind wing into the fuselage.  Many streamlined designs have tapered, swept tips and/or winglets to lower vortex interference with the upper wing low pressure area.

Comment: Shouldn't that be included in your answer?  ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall that which interferes with lift is higher pressure from under the wing curling over the top of the wing.  The vortex proper forms from this **and** inflow of surrounding air into the downwash sheet.  Maybe semantics, but the lift killer near the upper wing surface may be a half (turn) vortex?  Notice approaching stall, higher pressure can "leak" in from the trailing edge too.  All this may not be in the neat form of vorticies.  Interestingly, with vortex generators (and delta wings), a stable vortex can actually help preserve lift.

Comment: You aren't getting the hint....

Comment: @MichaelHall please read section 2.2.2 (page 16) in the reference linked in quietflyer's answer.  There the cause of rolling tendency (mentioned in the question) is discussed.

Comment: From my comments above, what makes you think I might be confused about rolling tendencies?  Again, you aren't getting the hint... I'm telling you that "*the relative wind may push the vortex further into the upwind wingtip and further away from the downwind wingtip*" **is the answer**. It is direct, simple, complete, and lacks nothing. That doesn't mean you can't supplement it with further discussion, but as you often do, you talk in circles around issues related to the question without actually answering it.  Would you like me to edit your answer to add that sentence at the top?

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't think you are confused.  I do think that "vortex" and its effects are vastly overrated and misunderstood.  Vortex creation can actually help lift in some cases.  I choose for focus on effects unique to the oblique wing which (from references) touch on the body of the question (pressure differential-->rolling).  Sort of amusing that my answer sought to clarify quietflyer's, and yours sought to clarify mine.  This is positive.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens to tip vortices in a sideslip?

*Going for brevity, and with thanks to another member here:*

The relative wind may push the vortex further into the upwind wingtip and further away from the downwind wingtip.

Comment: Might that not tend to diminish the strength of the vortex on the upwind side?  Currently addressed to some extent in some comments under my answer, may move into actual answer later--

Comment: @quietflyer, perhaps it would, but I don't intend to supplement my answer with further discussion at this time.